# Merge a door and a wall in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, merge

I have in a room and a door in two different layers. I want to add the door to the wall so that it looks realistic, now it does not look like the door belongs to the wall or that it is glued. I have no problem with the door changing color if it is not possible without the door changing color.

I have tested Edit --> Auto-blend layers but it change the color/light in the room.

How can I merge a door (in silver on the imgage below) to the wall in Photoshop?

[image]

Comment: It’s not just a matter of merging two objects here. The light source on the door is clearly different from the one in the room (it’s coming from the top right instead of top centre), so you’d have to fix the lit/shadowy areas on the door as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not simple, needs several fixes.

At first the light should come from the ceiling. I approximated it by clipping the gate to a new layer. I guess you already have it as a separate layer. The layer was rotated and it got layer style "Drop shadow" to make a shadow below the gate:

[image]

The next step is to match the color:

[image]

It has adjustment layer Hue&Saturation in colorize mode. I had a layer mask to prevent colorizing the background. The mask is got from the same selection I used to clip the gate. As well you could set the "next layer switch only" ON.

The trickiest part is to match top and bottom lights. I used 2 differently masked curves layers. Layer Curves 1 affects to the whole gate equally and increases the contrast. The goal was to match the gloss on the top.

[image]

Layer Curves 2 affects more to the bottom and it makes the bottom darker. Black was painted manually with soft brush to the layer mask to keep the top side gloss intact.

[image]

The colorizing layer must be on top because curves layers would affect the color saturation.

I guess someone finds a way to make this with less layers, but I see it's useful to simplify the thinking needs with more layers.

ADD due a comment:

User @Scott says that more is needed for perfect result. He is right. The door iris has a non-fitting reflection at 4 o'clock. It should be either removed by cloning or moved to 12 or 6 o'clock depending on the surface curvature of the door. Also the bright reflected arc around the bottom half of the door iris should be adjusted to less offensive.

**Further tests:**

Just for curiosity I tried to draw my own gate in Illustrator. That removes light direction problems. Of course it has other errors, for ex. wrong surface texture. The result:

[image]

The gate has 2 parts: The body and the door line pattern. Both are pasted separately from Illustrator. In Photoshop Door lines got layer style Bevel&Emboss for the apparent depth and the body got a drop shadow.

In Illustrator the door lines are circle arcs and the body is made by applying 3D effect Revolve:

[image]

Colorization and final light adjustments have the same adjustment layers as above, but with different settimgs to match the lighter shape. The gate surface noise pattern has low opacity and blending mode =Multiply.

Comment: Spin the door -45° as well so the center highlights match. `:)` That bottom "flare" makes little sense unless the floor is a mirror. But I suppose it depends on whether you see it as convex or concave.

Comment: @Scott That’s just a reflection of the flash used to take the picture, duh. ;-)